# Record showing twice if it's updated

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I am updating a record, it becomes double on the screen.

Here is the way I am loading it

```
   ngOnInit() {
    this.loadItems();
    }
    
      loadItems(){
        this.first_time_enter = true;
        console.log(this.first_time_enter);
        this.tableData = [];   
      let query3 =  firebase.firestore().collection('complaints').where('complaint_status', '==', "Open")
       query3
       .orderBy("complaint_date","desc").limit(2)
       .onSnapshot(querySnapshot=> {  
         querySnapshot.forEach(doc=> {
                      var data = Object.assign(doc.data(), {docid : doc.id}, {duration: duration})
             this.tableData.push(data);
             console.log(this.tableData);
         });
}
```

I am showing `this.tableData` array on the html.

When page loads, I see **2** entries and if **I update anything from Firebase console**, they become **4**. How do I manage this, I believe this is happening due to  `this.tableData.push(data);` but I am emptying this same array `this.tableData = []` above query which doesn't seem to work.

See pics below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I assume, if you reload the page, you get the right results, right? I can guess you are just appending the results of the current array, I can help you better with more information. Do u use lodash?

Comment: Yes, if I reload it will be fine, but I don't want to. Appending is the culprit, any other way to manage this ? I am  ot aware of lodash. I am using query snapshot of firebase, it fetches the changed data and I am appending it  , emptying this array above the query snapshot code is not getting called

Comment: that's what I figured, puff gave you the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time there are any changes to the complaints, your callback gets called with a `querySnapshot` that contains all complaints **including the ones that aren't changed**.

You will either need to only process the documents that were changed, or clear your `tableData`. Since the latter is the simplest:

```
  let query3 =  firebase.firestore().collection('complaints').where('complaint_status', '==', "Open")
   query3
   .orderBy("complaint_date","desc").limit(2)
   .onSnapshot(querySnapshot=> {  
     this.tableData = []; // clear previous results
     querySnapshot.forEach(doc=> {
                  var data = Object.assign(doc.data(), {docid : doc.id}, {duration: duration})
         this.tableData.push(data);
         console.log(this.tableData);
     });
```